# Настройки AppVeyor для сборки нескольких проектов

Tags: .net, build, devops, непрерывная-интеграция, ci-cd

У меня вопрос по AppVeyor, может кто-то использует его в связке с GitHub. Я когда-то настраивал его для одного проекта PET, но недавно переписал его и теперь добавил в него несколько библиотек, а билд сломался, не могу исправить. Я не знаю, как правильно написать скрипт для нескольких решений. Ссылка - [Build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Ledrunning/tinnymonitor). Ссылка на [репозиторий](https://github.com/Ledrunning/TinnyMonitor/tree/master/TinyMonitorApp). Есть только одно но, скрипт находится внутри директории с основным приложением. На прикрепленном скриншоте стрелка указывает на файл appveyor.yml. Второй вопрос, куда его нужно будет переместить?

Дерево проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам скрипт:

```
image: Visual Studio 2022
branches:
only:
  - master

configuration: Release
environment:
major_version: 1
minor_version: 7
patch_version: 0
version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version).{build}'
dotnet_csproj:
patch: true
file: 'TinyMonitorApp\TinyMonitorApp.csproj'
package_version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version)'
assembly_version: '{version}'
file_version: '{version}'
informational_version: '{version}'

before_build: 
  # Display .NET version
  - cmd: dotnet --version
  # Display minimal restore text
  - cmd: dotnet restore
build_script:
  - cmd: dotnet build -c Release
artifacts:
  - path: TinyMonitorApp\bin\Release\TinyMonitorApp.exe
name: TinyMonitor

deploy:
release: tinymonitor-v$(APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)
description: 'Release version'
provider: GitHub
auth_token:
secure: token
artifact: /.*\.nupkg/            # upload all NuGet packages to release assets
draft: false
prerelease: false
on:
branch: master                 # release from master branch only
APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG: true        # deploy on tag push only
```